# OSError micropython

Tags: micropython, oserror

I get OSError on esp8266. First request is successful but second and more are failed with OSError, I dont know why. Can you help me?

Edit: I solved it. I wrote the solution at the end of the codes.

```
import network
name, password="wifiname", "passwordd"
wlan = network.WLAN(network.STA_IF)
wlan.active(True)       # activate the interface
wlan.scan()             # scan for access points
wlan.isconnected()      # check if the station is connected to an AP
wlan.connect(name, password) # connect to an AP
wlan.config('mac')      # get the interface's MAC address
wlan.ifconfig()         # get the interface's IP/netmask/gw/DNS addresses
ap = network.WLAN(network.AP_IF) # create access-point interface
ap.active(True)         # activate the interface
ap.config(essid='ESP-AP') # set the ESSID of the access point
print('Wifi connected! My IP:', wlan.ifconfig()[0])

import urequests
import time

while 1:
    try:
        t1=time.time()
        r=urequests.get('https://saitamatechnoo.web.app/')
        t2=time.time()
        print(r.status_code, 'Time:', t2-t1)
    except OSError:
        print('error')
```

Guys, I solved it. It works with socket and we should close every socket after using it.

For example:

```
r=urequests.get('https://saitamatechnoo.web.app/')
print(r.status_code)
r.close()
```